# Publicar una imagen con previsualización en Facebook del usuario, mediante código PHP o javascript,

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web, facebook

Quisiera conseguir, mediante javascript o PHP, que al presionar un botón en el sitio web, el usuario pueda ver previsualizada una imagen en una ventana de Facebook para poder compartirla si así lo desea.

Compartir texto parece ser muy fácil, con algo así:

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=TITULO&amp;p[url]=URL&amp;p[images][0]=IMAGEN&amp;p[summary]=TEXTO' target="_blank">Botón</a>
```

Pero sólo me funciona con el texto o con la url, he intentado varias maneras de conseguir publicar una imagen al igual que consigo publicar texto pero no sé qué estoy haciendo mal. El código anterior por ejemplo no me está funcionando para la imagen.

¿Alguien me pueda guiar un poco? muchas gracias.

Comment: No puedes crear contenido artificial para compartir en facebook. Facebook internamente lee las etiquetas meta (lee sobre SEO) y con eso renderiza una imagen destacada, título, descripción, etc. Puede hacer uso de su herramienta Sharing Debugger para ir testeando el cómo se verá esa url final compartida en esta red social. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Answer (score 2):

En el apartado en inglés de StackOverflow tenemos una pregunta similar, te adjunto el ejemplo y la url de la documentación de facebook

Espero te sirva de ayuda,
Un saludo!!

[Esta es la pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602544/share-an-image-in-facebook-via-php/25604336)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/

```
<?php
// require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
require_once("/YOUR_PATH_TO/facebook_php_sdk/facebook.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
  "access_token" => "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
  "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
  "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
  "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Sugiero adjuntes el enlace de la pregunta, para referencia Saludos

Comment: Gracias @Aprendiz lo tenía en mente, pero la familia me llamó y se me olvidó adjuntarlo jejeje